# Перейти в другое приложение по кнопке

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Подскажите как в андроиде реализовать переход из одного приложения в другое по нажатию соответствующей кнопки?

Если быть точнее, мне нужно из моего приложения при нажатии на кнопку "Skype" перейти в Skype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если скайп установлен, то он запустится, иначе - откроется страничка скайпа в маркете :

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider");
if (intent != null)
{
    // start the activity
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
    // bring user to the market
    // or let them choose an app?
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+"com.skype.raider"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Подскажите еще где брать этот адрес (com.skype.raider) для других приложений? Например для viber, whatsapp и т.п.

Comment: можно погуглить (intent for launch viber/whatsap/*** android) и в первых 3х ссылках будет ответ.

Comment: либо находишь в маркете приложение, например вибер. его ссылка - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip . в конце ссылки видем его ID.